# Merge dataframes with different column variables

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge

```r
df1
"ID" "df1"
var1   100
var2   300
var3   400
var5   300

df2
"ID" "df2"
var1  100
var2  200
var4  300
var5  400
```

to make

```r
"ID" "df1"  "df2" 
var1  100   100 
var2  200   300
var3  400   NA
var4  400   300
var5  300   400
```

and apply this to a list of csv files with `lapply`. The aim being to create a csv file with a single ID column for each variable (ID), and each reading from the csv list as a separate column, like below.

```
final
ID    df1    df2    df3    df4    df5 
var1
var2
var3
var4
var5
```

`merge` works perfectly when I'm specifying files one by one, but trying to loop it overwrites write.csv with the final item in my `list.files` list.

My code currently looks like this:

```r
sheetname<-str_split_fixed(foo_bar,"_")[1]
    if(file.exists(paste0(dir,sheet_name)) == FALSE) {
        write.csv(file=(paste0(dir,sheet_name,".csv")),x=1,row.names=FALSE)
        }

new_file<-read.csv(paste0(dir,sheet_name,".csv"),header=TRUE)
colnames(datafile)[2] = paste0(str_split_fixed(foo_bar_foo_1,"_",n=4)[4])
colnames(new_file)[1] = "ID"

   final<- merge(x=new_file,y=csv_single,all=TRUE)
write.csv(final, file = paste0(enddir,sheet_name,".csv"),row.names = FALSE)

}
```

I'd like to create a csv in my directory if it doesn't already exist, then name the first column ID, which matches my ID column in other csv files. Then, rename my column names in my spreadsheets to be a little more readable.

Finally, I'd like to merge one of my dataframes with the newly created `new_file`, where at each iteration it will rewrite my dataframe over the old one, rewriting the file and adding unique rows and a column for each new dataframe.

Where have I gone wrong here?

Comment: You haven't shown us your loop; what are you looping over? How do you generate the vector/list to generate over? Do you have strong reasons to write the intermediate data frame to file in each iteration?

Comment: I'm using list.files to generate my list and lapply(listedfiles,thisfunction) to do it. I don't have a particularly good reason for writing an intermediate file, this is my first time using R (or any programming language for that matter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is small, let's divide things up in steps:

1: Read list of file names:

```
files_to_read <- list.files(...)
```

2: Load data, and check that your data and check that it works properly. *But*, as this is a separate step that is to be repeated for independent files, we'll write a function:

```
read_my_file <- function(fn) {
  df <- read.csv(fn)
  # check check check.. er...
  if (ncol(df) != 2)
    return(NULL) ## don't return an invalid data frame
  if (names(df)[1] != ID')
    return(NULL)
  # The amount of checking depends on how paranoid you are and how much (or little) you trust the input files.
  # If everything is fine, return the data
  return(df)
}
```

3: In R, explicit looping can be slow and we are usually adviced to use the `*apply`-family of methods, as you correctly found with `lapply`.

```
all_my_data_frames <- lapply(files_to_read, read_my_file)
# remove NULL elements:
didnotwork <- sapply(all_my_data_frames, is.null)
all_my_data_frames <- all_my_data_frames[!didnotwork]
```

`all_my_data_frames` is now a *list*-object. Check it out with `str(all_my_data_frames)`. You should have an element for each 
filename in `files_to_read`. We then check if any of the list's elements are `NULL` (something went wrong) and then subset those that were read correctly.

4: `Reduce` is your friend here. I cannot try this solution, by this should get you started. Notice that I'm using an *anonymous function*, because sometimes we cannot be bothered to name a function just to use it once...

```
Reduce(function(a,b) merge(a,b,by='ID', all=TRUE), x)
```

although you could do it manually with a loop. However, the `*apply`-family of methods generally don't work very well when the iterations are dependent on each other (either by being dependent on previous iteration or accessing/updating external files or variables). So you would be best of with a loop:

```
res <- data.frame(ID=character(0)) ## initiate
for (i in seq_along(all_my_data_frames)) {
  if (is.null(all_my_data_frames[[i]])) ## notice double brackets!
    next
  res <- merge(res, all_my_data_frames[[i]], by='ID', all=TRUE)
}
```

The advantage of this is that you can check on-the-fly if you should skip an element.

Comment: Reduce worked like an absolute charm. Thanks so much for the help!